# I want to make the head and arms as different objects which are as single mesh now with the bone structure intact

Tags: animation, mesh, armature, bones

I am a new and novice in blender.
I want to use the head and arms as separate objects than the body. But I have them attached together and the bones are also created and set as if they are together. Now I want to make the head and arms as different objects with bones as it was before ie without destroying the bone structure and its functionality. so that i can use them in unity and switch the head on and off.

Please pardon My English.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if it does or doesn't corrupt your animation data as the weights possibly change but here a workflow worth a try:

1. Select the mesh and go in edit mode 'tab'.
2. Select the head press <kbd>Y</kbd> to split the geometry.
3. Repeat the process for the arms.
4. While still being in edit mode press <kbd>P</kbd> and select "separate by loose parts".

This should separate the geometry into parts. I'm not sure how this will affect the armature / binding and animations.

-> run an animation to check if that already solved your issues

If the bindings are lost (arms / head etc, don't react to the bones):

1. Select all objects you want to bind to the rig.
2. Select the rig last.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and select "With Automatic Weight".

Run an animation - if the deformations are weird, you probably have to take a look into weight painting.